# Filtering GeoRSSLayer contents in ArcGIS API for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo, filter, georss

I would like to make use of a public geoRSS feed with content from 10years (200+ items), however since it is too much information, i would like to show only a subset of this content in my map.

I have been unable to find any reference of how to filter/query the content of an [esri georsslayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/georsslayer-amd.html#georsslayer1) with the JS API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I failed to find a documented solution for this problem. However i did solve it by looping through once the layer is loaded and hiding all the items which did not meet my criteria, as below:

```
    dojo.forEach(tmpLayer.items,function(s) //tmpLayer is georsslayer name
    {
        var pointDate = new Date(s.attributes['pubDate']); //the graphic attribute to filter
        if (pointDate > LastMonth) //if successful symbolise the graphic
        {
            //here i am using another function to set icon based on attribute value;
            s.setSymbol(getCategoryIcon(s.attributes['category']));
            s.setInfoTemplate(geoRSSTemplate);
        }
        else //else hide it
        {
            s.hide();
        }
    });
```